# Computer making various noises and sometimes runs slowly

Tags: hard-drive, audio, motherboard, power-supply, fan

My computer has been making some very strange noises for several months now. The first noise it made was when I installed Speed Fan and after the second time of running the program, my computer made a noise that sounded like faulty car brakes. The system also started to run ungodly slow, and I had to hard reset it. Speed Fan also froze completely. All of this happened right when Speed Fan tried to do something to an ISA bus (the program's console said this), which is strange because my computer doesn't have one. I immediately uninstalled Speed Fan, and everything was fine for a while.

Then last month I began to overclock my system, and then after I had a stable setup, more noises came. They're sort of like squeaky sounds that just come and go, and they are more common when I have something in the front USB ports. But this time, the system runs at it's regular speed. It doesn't affect this system, or at least I hope it isn't, but the noise is very annoying.

And finally today, at the time of this question, the computer did the same exact Speed Fan failure mentioned above immediately as I logged in to Windows, but a reboot fixed it.

I am really puzzled as to what is wrong with my system. I don't think it's coil wine, because I've never heard of that crippling a computer's performance. I also don't think it's my PSU. It has problems and will be replaced soon, but the reason why I ruled it out was because a couple of months ago, I pushed it to near overload when I tried to upgrade my graphics card to some sort of ATI card, can't remember the model, but the entire system was near silent, and would only shut off from power surging. The noise sounds like it's coming from the hard drive area, but the noise also comes when they are idle as well as under full load. I checked all of the fans, and even replaced one. Can anybody help me figure this out, I am completely stumped. Here is my setup:

M3N78-VM motherboard

GeForce 8400GS graphics

6GB 800Mhz DDR2 RAM (only 3.3 GB usable)

Maxtor DiamondMax 21 320GB SATA HDD

Seagate Barracuda 1TB SATA HDD

450Watt PSU

AMD Athlon X2 2.5 GHz CPU (overclocked to 2.87 GHz)

Windows 7 32bit

Something else I should mention, there is a big mish-mash of wires that include the SATA cables and USB cables, along with just about every other cable in the system beside power and fans. Could that possibly be the culprit? Maybe the USB cables are interfering with the SATA cables when I have a USB device plugged in? Just a thought.

Comment: It sounds like it all started with Speed Fan.  Try uninstalling it.  What you describe sounds like motor bearing noise (either fan or hard drive).  Given the other symptoms and information, my bet is on a fan.

Comment: @fixer1234 I already did. But I will try the fans again now... nope, not the fans. It sounds like it's coming off of my mobo, near the chipset.

Comment: Did you check the heat sink fans?

Comment: @fixer1234 Yes, and I also noticed my chipset heat sink is very very hot. even with the case open. Here are my hardware temps, tell me if anything is unordinary: RAM 38C, CPU 39C, Graphics card: 37C, HDDs 36C, PSU case 34C, CPU power Mosfets 36C, chipset heatsink 48C. And noise is back when I plugged a FTDI cable into the USB port.

Comment: @fixer1234 Okay, I did some research, and I found out my chipset is running at 62C, where the max temp is 65C. I may have to turn my overvoltage down on it to prevent damage, and that may also fix my noise problem.

Comment: Your question describes a lot of stuff and it's a little hard to figure out what are old problems that no longer exist and what are the current symptoms (and whether Speed Fan is still installed).  If you are hearing squeaky noises coming from your hard drive, that could be bearing failure or the heads scraping oxide off the platter, neither of which is good but the latter means imminent failure.  Post back whether your adjustment fixes everything.